# How to show a value in a new table depending on which radio button is clicked?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Below is my table in the jsp page which is getting generated dynamically -

```
<Table id="firstTable">
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${reportData.getHash().size() - 1}">
    <TR>
    <TD>
        <input type="radio" name="test" id="radioButton">
    </TD>
    <TD>
        <span id="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
    </TD>
    <TD>
    ${Data.getValue1().get(i)}
    </TD>
    </TR>
</c:forEach>
</Table>
```

Here first column in the first row is `radio button`, and second column in the first row is `GenId`. Similarly, first column in the second row is `radio button`, and second column in the second row is different `GenId`. And similarly for other rows and column...

**Problem Statement:-**

Now what I am suppose to do is -  As soon as I click on each radio button in a particular row, I would like to show value of `GeId` in a new table just below the `firstTable`.

- So suppose if I click first row radio button and value of `GenId` was `10` in first row, then I would show `10` value in a new table just below the `firstTable`.
- And now if I click second row radio button and value of `GenId` is `20` in second row, then it should show `20` value only in the new table just below `firstTable`...

So I got the below jquery code which works fine for only first row radio button, meaning if I click first row radio button then it is making a new table properly with the `GenId` value, but it doesn't work for second row radio button... And if I keep on clicking first row radio button, then it keeps on generating a new table always.. I just need to have one table which should show value basis on whether I am clicking first radio button or second radio button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radioButton').click(function() {

        alert($('#importantColumnData').html());

        var tableText = '<table id="newTable">';
            tableText += '<tr>';
            tableText += '<td>';
            tableText += $('#importantColumnData').html();
            tableText += '</td>';
            tableText += '</tr>';
        tableText += '</table>';
        $('#firstTable').after(tableText);
    });
});
```

I guess as the id of radio button is always same for each table row, may be that's why it is not working?

What wrong I am doing in my above code? Can anyone provide a simple jsfiddle example which can help me to understand?

**UPDATE:-**

This is my `firstTable` rendered html -

```
<TABLE id="firstTable" name="FirstTable">
    <TR style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#787878;">
        <TH>Select</TH>
        <TH>GenId</TH>
    </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <input type="radio" name="radioValue" value="some value" id="radioButton">
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <span id="importantColumnData" name="colDat">16192153</span>

            </TD>
        </TR>

        <TR>
            <TD>
                <input type="radio" name="radioValue" value="some value" id="radioButton">
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <span id="importantColumnData" name="colDat">19745383</span>

            </TD>
        </TR>
</TABLE>
```

As soon as I am clicking first row radio button, it should show `16192153` value in the new table just below `firsTable` and if I am clicking second row radio button, then it should show `19745383` value in the same new table only just below `firstTable`..

**ANOTHER UPDATE:-**

I am able to make that work with the suggestions you guys have suggested..

Now I am seeing one more issue.. After getting `importantColumnData` value, I am passing it to `connection.jsp` page which will use this value to make a query against a database using `ajax` and then it return backs the response in the `data` value.. And now I am using this `data` value to iterate and grab all the values from it and put it in a `newTable` as shown below -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.radioButton').click(function () {

    alert($(this).closest("tr").find(".importantColumnData").text());
    var importantColumnData = $(this).closest("tr").find(".importantColumnData").text();

    $.getJSON("connection.jsp", {'name': importantColumnData}, function (data) {

        // added as per suggestion
        if($("#newTable").length == 0) {
            var tableText = '<table id="newTable" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="1" style="text-align:center;">';
            tableText +='<br/><br/>';
            tableText +='<tr style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#787878;">'
            tableText += '<th>Category Name</th>';
            tableText +='<th>Attributes</th>';
            tableText +='<th>Libraries</th>';
            tableText +='<th>Developer</th>';
            tableText += '<th>Sources</th>';
            tableText +='</tr>';
            var tbl_body = "";
            $.each(data, function () {
                var tbl_row = "";
                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    tbl_row += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
                })
                tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
            })
            tableText += "<tbody>" + tbl_body + "</tbody>";
            $('#firstTable').after(tableText);
    } else {
        // added as per suggestion
        $("#newTable tr td").text(importantColumnData);
    }
    });

});
});
</script>
```

So for the first time, when I click first row radio button, it shows me the correct value in new table but if I again click the same radio button, then it is showing me only `importantColumnData` across all the columns in that row which is wrong.. Instead of that it should show the same column values which was shown when I click for the first time..

As I can see in the else block I am just putting only `importantColumnData` value.. How do I modify this to start showing the original column values which was shown for the first time when I clicked the first row radio button?

Comment: You can not implement the same solution for AJAX interaction.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {

        if( $(this).prop('checked') ){
            var text = $(this).parent().next(".importantColumnData").text(),
                tableText = '<table id="newTable"><tr><td>'+ text +'</td></tr></table>';
                $('#newTable').remove();
                $('body').append(tableText);
        }
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9y8h/7/)

Comment: It doesn't work..It only has one radio button in your jsfiddle example and if I keep on clicking radio button, it keeps on generating a new table everytime.. In short it should show only one table with the value.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh.. Can you add couple of radio button example as well in the JSFiddle you have just to complete the answer so that I can test that out as well?

Comment: @akiiddweeber: I have update my answer with multipal radio buttons. [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9y8h/7/)

Comment: Thanks Rakesh.. Your solution also works fine.. I have updated my question with my last final changes which is not working correctly.. As it is related to this question only so I am not opening a new post otherwise people will take long time to understand what is happening.. Take a look and see if you can help out one last time.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Change your table like below (just changed id to class and apply rel for value)-

```
<Table id="firstTable">
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${reportData.getHash().size() - 1}">
    <TR>
    <TD>
        <input type="radio" name="test" class="radioButton" rel="${Data.getValue1().get(i)}">
    </TD>
    <TD>
        <span id="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
    </TD>
    <TD>
    ${Data.getValue1().get(i)}
    </TD>
    </TR>
</c:forEach>
</Table>
```

jQuery should be like below -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.radioButton').click(function() {
        var genId = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#newTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+genId+'</td></tr>');        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong is that you are using id instead of classes. `#importantColumnData` and `#radioButton` should be unique. Change your HTML and JS accordingly:

```
<TR>
    <TD>
        <input type="radio" name="test" name="radioButton" class="radioButton">
    </TD>
    <TD>
        <span class="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
    </TD>
    <TD>${Data.getValue1().get(i)}</TD>
</TR>
```

and js:

```
$('.radioButton').click(function() {
    alert($('.importantColumnData', $(this).closest('tr')).html());
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/77mPc/

Comment: I tried this.. If I click on first radio button, it popup with the value of `GenId` for first row which is correct.. But if I click on second row radio button, then it shows the value of first `GenId` in the popup which is wrong... It should show the value of second `GenId` in the second row.. Any thoughts what wrong is going on?

Comment: Thanks dfsq for the help.. Can you also add an example in your jsfiddle which shows the data in the new table along with popup just below the `firstTable` as well? It will help me a lot in testing this out here on jsfiddle..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have one last doubt.. As it is related to this question only and the exercise which I am doing currently.. I am using this `importantColumnData` value to make a call against database and then whatever response I am getting back from database, I am storing them in `data` variable.. And then I am using this data variable to iterate and then show the data in a `newTable`. And with that I am facing an issue.. See if you can help out.. I thought I can directly use your solution which will get integrated in my solution but somehow I was wrong.. See if you can help out..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#radioButton').click(function() {

    alert($('#importantColumnData').html());


        var tableText="";

        if($("#newTable").length == 0) 
        tableText += '<table id="newTable">';
        tableText += '<tr>';
        tableText += '<td>';
        tableText += $('#importantColumnData').html();
        tableText += '</td>';
        tableText += '</tr>';

        if($("#newTable").length == 0) 
        { 
          tableText += '</table>';
          $('#firstTable').after(tableText);
        }
       else
         $('#newTable').html(tableText);
    });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have one last doubt.. As it is related to this question only and the exercise which I am doing currently.. I am using this `importantColumnData` value to make a call against database and then whatever response I am getting back from database, I am storing them in data variable.. And then I am using this data variable to iterate and then show the data in a newTable. And with that I am facing an issue.. See if you can help out.. I thought I can directly use your solution which will get integrated in my solution but somehow I was wrong.. See if you can help out..

Answer (score 1):

Remove Id and add classes to Radio button and SPAN element 
See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7R2dA/)

```
<table id="firstTable">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="radioButton"></td>
        <td><span class="importantColumnData">10</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="radioButton"></td>
        <td><span class="importantColumnData">20</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radio" class="radioButton"></td>
        <td><span class="importantColumnData">30</span></td>
    </tr>

</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.radioButton').click(function() {                
            var importantColumnData = $(this).closest("tr").find(".importantColumnData").text();                
           if($("#newTable").length == 0)
           {
            console.log(importantColumnData);
                var tableText = '<table id="newTable">';
                    tableText += '<tr>';
                    tableText += '<td>';
                    tableText += importantColumnData;
                    tableText += '</td>';
                    tableText += '</tr>';
                    tableText += '</table>';
                $('#firstTable').after(tableText);
            }
            else{
                $("#newTable tr td").text(importantColumnData);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Your solution worked but once I tried integrating in my application code.. I am facing another issue which I have updated in my question..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#firstTable tr td').on('click',function(){
    var nextTdText = $(this).next().children('span').text();
     if($('#newTable').length == 0){
    var newTable="<table id="newTable"><tr><td id="clickedVal"></td></tr></table>";
     $('#firstTable').after(newTable);
     }
     $('#clickedVal').text(nextTdText);

  });
});
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot.. I have one last doubt.. As it is related to this question only and the exercise which I am doing currently.. I am using this importantColumnData value to make a call against database and then whatever response I am getting back from database, I am storing them in data variable.. And then I am using this data variable to iterate and then show the data in a newTable. And with that I am facing an issue.. See if you can help out.. I thought I can directly use your solution which will get integrated in my solution but somehow I was wrong.. See if you can help out..